# put a string with numbers and letters into an int pointer within a struct

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers, integer

```
typedef struct Int40
{
  int *digits;
} Int40;




  Int40 *parseString(char *str)
{
    Int40 *p;

    int i;
    int *intPtr;
    printf("%s\n", str);

    p->digits = malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        p->digits = atoi(str);
        printf("%d\n", p->digits);
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

    Int40 *p;

    parseString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567");
    return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to put the string "012345679abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567" into the struct pointer digits, however I am not sure how I should be doing this.

My error with this current program is 'passing argument 1 of atoi makes pointer from integer without a cast

And if I remove the [i] from str[i] and p->digits[i]

```
p->digits[i] = atoi(str[i]);
```

then I am returned only 123456789 for my result

EDIT**
I added a malloc into the parseString function
I'm trying to figure out how to convert the char *str into int format using the int *digits in the struct

Comment: Allocate space first.  You need space for the `struct Int40` that `p` points to, and for the characters (presumably up to 41 of them) that `p->digits` will point to.

Comment: It is not clear what you hope to achieve. What value(s) are you expecting to get stored, and where?

Comment: You are not allocating memory wich will result in runetime error, the compile error is because atoi expects a ponter and you are passing a char as a parameter

Comment: Do you want to store the digits as individual characters?  In hex?  If so, you don't need to call `atoi` at all.

Comment: I want to print the p->digits in another function eventually resulting in
"0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567"

Comment: Are you wanting to convert a single digit at a time, or are you wanting to convert the biggest number string you can from your current position?

Comment: Yes, so just print the string you have? I know that doesn't answer your question, so think harder about my question.

Comment: You need, somewhere, the line `p = malloc(sizeof(Int40))`.  Then you also need `p->digits = malloc(41)`.  Also you need to check the return value of `malloc`.  Also you need to null-terminate the `digits` string after you copy it.  Also, if these suggestions of mine aren't making sense, if they sound like they refer to concepts you've never heard of, you need to spend more time with your C book and make sure you understand these concepts, before you try to write this program.

Comment: The `malloc` call you added is wrong.  `sizeof(str)` is going to be either 4 or 8, for separate reasons which needn't concern us here for the moment.  Also you still need memory for what `p` points to.  Also, I was wrong: if `digits` is supposed to be an array of `int`, my suggestion of `malloc(41)` was wrong.  If you want to convert the hexadecimal digits characters `'0'` thriugh `'9' and `'a'` through `'f'` to integers, you're going to need to do that either with `strtoul` and a base of 16, or by calling `isdigit` and `isalpha` or `isxdigit` and subtracting offsets like `'0'` and `'a'`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to read an introductory C textbook and learn a little more before you try to write this program.

Comment: Occazn: Posted code does not compile, at least due to a missing `}`.  Posting non-compilable code attacks negative votes and make for an unnecessary effort to assist.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confused about a few things.

1) Memory allocation

```
 p->digits = malloc(sizeof(str) + 1);
```

This is allocation for string but `p->digits` is a pointer of `int` type.

2) The function `atoi`

```
int atoi(const char *str);
```

Returns `int` value.
Maximum value for a variable of type `int` is `2147483647`
Check: [limits.h](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm).

If you use `long long int` it can give you `19` digits.
Do you need more digits than `long long int` can give you?

3) Remember to allocate memory for the structure and also remember to release it.

Check the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LLint19
{
   long long int *digits;
} LLInt19;

long long int sg7_atoi(const char *c)
{
    long long int value = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if( *c == '+' || *c == '-' )
    {
        if( *c == '-' ) sign = -1;
        c++;
    }
    while (*c >= '0' && *c <= '9') // to detect digit == isdigit(*c))
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += (int) (*c-'0');
        c++;
    }
    return (value * sign);
}

LLInt19 *parseString(char *str)
{
    LLInt19 *p;
    long long int *value;

    printf("Input  str: %s\n", str);

    value = malloc (sizeof(long long int) ); // allocate memory for long long int value

    p = malloc( sizeof(LLInt19) );           // allocate memory for the structure

    *value  = sg7_atoi(str);                 // do a conversion string to long long int

    p->digits = value;

    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LLInt19 *p;

    char test1[] = "1234567890123456789";

    p = parseString(test1);

    printf("Output str: %lld \n", *p->digits);

    free(p->digits);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input  str: 1234567890123456789                                                                                                             
Output str: 1234567890123456789
```