# Adding two members of a struct together

Tags: c, struct

```
    typedef struct Int40
{
  // a dynamically allocated array to hold a 40
  // digit integer, stored in reverse order
  int *digits;
} Int40;
```

in main I have these functions implemented, and loadCryptoVariable and loadHwConfigVariable each return a 40 digit value

```
Int40 *p;
  Int40 *q;
  Int40 *r;
    p = loadCryptoVariable("cryptoVarFile");
      q = loadHWConfigVariable(0);
     r = kw26Add( p, q);
```

However, I can't figure out how to add the two together..(side note: I am aware I shouldn't malloc like that and use a more defined way to do it, however, I'm just attempting to figure out the add at the moment)

```
Int40 *kw26Add(Int40 *p, Int40 *q)
{
    Int40 *result;
    result = malloc(300);
    result->digits = malloc(300);

    result->digits = p->digits + q->digits;

     return result;
}
```

Comment: You are storing a single digit of the 40-digit number in each array index? Or you are packing a (roughly) 20-byte value into the array?

Comment: Presumably this is a continuation of the code asked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137431).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but as I read it, you would need to iterate through the array.  For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    result->digits[i] = p->digits[i] + q->digits[i];
```

Comment: @Occazn But you're probably also going to have to worry about the carry.

Comment: @SteveSummit What do you mean the carry? as in the 40 digit will become 41 digits?

Comment: @Occazn I'm still not sure how your digits are represented (what base you're using).  But in decimal, if I add the numbers 123 and 491, the second digit of the sum is *not* 11.  So when you add `p->digits[i]` and `q->digits[i]`, you're not quite done.  (And, yes, if digit overflow happens on the 40th digit, the proper sum will have 41 digits.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Does that happen for all digits when added together? As in if 3 were added to 9, it would only return 2? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: @Occazn Yes, of course there's a way to fix it!  (Otherwise we couldn't do arithmetic.)  The way to fix it is called "carrying".  If you know how to do arithmetic yourself, you already understand this, although you may know it by another name.  There's a Wikipedia article on it: [Carry (arithmetic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)).

Comment: @SteveSummit I think I understand it! Thank you for your help, and for following me question to question haha