# Adding two large numbers together

Tags: c, struct, numbers, addition

I have two large numbers stored in an array(p->numbers[50] and q->numbers[50]), and printed out in hexadecimal

```
1319df046
111111111
```

When added together, I am returned with, in hexadecimal,

242af'11'257

However, apparently my answer "should" be

242af0157

There is a discrepancy when adding the f and 1 together, equaling 17, but printing 11 (as 17 is 11 in hexadecimal). I'm not sure why my output should be a 0 instead of 11

```
int sum = 0;
int carry = 0;
for(i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sum = p->numbers[i] + q->numbers[i];

    sum = sum + carry;

    answer[i] = sum;

    carry = sum / 10;

    printf("%x", answer[i]);
}
```

Comment: Are your `numbers` arrays supposed to be base-16? If so, it doesn’t make sense to carry `sum / 10`. `answer[i]` should also only store the remainder when divided by the base, `sum % 16` or `sum % 10`.

Comment: the numbers in the array are stored as decimal, but should be printed as hexadecimal

Comment: when I do answer[i] = sum % 10; instead, my result becomes 242057257, printed in hexadecimal

Comment: You can’t convert decimal to hex digit by digit like that. You have to convert the whole number.

Comment: @Ryan The numbers are stored as decimal, but only printed as hexadecimal. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by converting the whole number

Comment: The algorithm makes no sense. You are doing arithmetic as if it were decimal, but printing digits as if it were hex. If it were purely decimal, then `answer[i] = sum % 10` but then you're thinking that printing the digit as hex converts to hex, but it doesn't. As Ryan says, you can't do the hex conversion digit by digit like that. If the digits are decimal, then you have to compute the result as an entire decimal number then go back and convert to hex. You're printing decimal digits, with addition overflows included, as hex, and including the carry in the next sum.

Comment: *"The numbers are stored as decimal"* So are you saying that 1319df046 is actually being stored as the digits 5 1 2 7 4 0 1 5 4 2?  Because that's what you're implying.

Comment: Oh, you all are right. It is stored as hexadecimal. My mistake.

Comment: This is turning into quite the saga.  Earlier episodes are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137431) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205149).

Comment: I might have to change my name to go under a new alias @SteveSummit

Comment: a decimal number and a hexadecimal number are exactly the same in memory.  The main difference is the decimal number is taken, 4 bits at a time (starting on the right end) and those 4 bits converted to a hex value in the range 0...F inclusive

Comment: @user3629249 What you say is true *for a built-in type like* `int` *or* `long int`.  But the code in this question is maintaining individual digits in separate cells of an `int[]` array, so the decimal representation *would* be different.  (And of course hex and decimal are not the only two choices. For example, I have my own program and library for doing multiprecision arithmetic, and it maintains numbers internally as arrays of integers holding the individual digits in base 2147483648.)

Comment: @user3629249 But you're right, for the individual digits in the cells of the various arrays, it doesn't really make sense to say whether they are "in" decimal or hexadecimal.  If one of them contains, say, `0x0d`, it equally contains decimal 13.  The ongoing questions in the commentary here about whether they represent decimal or hexadecimal digits concerns the overall number represented by all the broken-down digits, and for the OP's code, that representation is, crucially, base 16.  The division by 10 when computing the carry in the originally-posted code was therefore in error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced your results by defining the arrays of digits as follows:

```
int p[] = {0x6,0x4,0x0,0xf,0xd,0x9,0x1,0x3,0x1,0x0};
int q[] = {0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x0};
```

This is *not* storing the number as decimal, but as hexadecimal digits.

With that in mind, there are three problems here:

First, the way you're calculating the carry is incorrect.  Because the digits are hexadecimal and not decimal, the carry should be `sum / 16` instead of `sum / 10`.

Second, when there is a carry involved, you're not removing the high digit of the sum.  In one place, you have 0xf + 0x1 + 0x1 = 0x11 and both characters are being printed.  You need to set the digit as `answer[i] = sum % 16;`

Third, you're adding the digits from largest to smallest.  You need to add them from smallest to largest in one loop, then print the digits from largest to smallest in a separate loop.

With those fixes in place, your code should look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sum = p[i] + q[i];
    sum = sum + carry;

    answer[i] = sum % 16;
    carry = sum / 16;
}

for(i=9; i>=0; i--) {
    printf("%x", answer[i]);
}
```

Comment: This returns 242af1257 instead of the 242af0157 that I am supposed to get as my answer. However, I understand my errors thinking that my stored values were decimal instead of hexadecimal. With this newfound knowledge, I am still unsure as to why the new program you wrote is different from the pre-defined answer.

Comment: @Occazn dbush's code works fine for me, giving `0242af0157`.  Perhaps you transcribed it incorrectly.

Comment: @SteveSummit Oh, I figured it out. Thank you all for your help

Comment: @Occazn Sounds like you may be adding the digits in the wrong order.  Make sure you're going from least significant to most significant.

Comment: @dbush Got it. Thank you, you've helped me understand this problem a lot more than I originally came in.